# Varying filepaths in C#

Tags: c#, date, formatting, filepath

I am creating C# Windows Form that retrieves files from shared drives as email attachments.  I am trying to automate the file retrieval process, but the filepaths available to me vary according to the date. For example:

- `V:\....\Dec-03\filename12-3-2013.xml`
- `J:\.....\December\filename12-4-2013`

I have the filepath stored as string from a textbox, but since the path varies slightly day-to-day, I've been trying to figure out how automate this process. In the past I've used VBA code where I've concatenated method calls into the string like this

```
"..." & Day(Date) & "..."
```

(I replaced the ampersand with the plus sign of course for C#)

But this just gets me an illegal characters in path Argument exception.

I am using a check for filedate and taking a a specific filepath through a textbox. I want particular files that are being updated in monthly folders and the filename contains a date. I want to grab the ones with today's date or yesterday's date, but some have no date in the filename or directory at all. Since there isn't a lot of consistency, I would love to enter code 
"+ DateTime.Now.ToString() +"
 in the textbox per individual filepath as I load them via the form and have the program execute like I've done with some VBA code, but I get Illegal characters with the double quotes in the middle of a filepath. Is there some work around or will I need to create fixes for every particular pattern?

Comment: I don't think it's fully clear what the problem is. Why can't you just call `Directory.GetFiles(path)` where `path` is the top-most folder that contains all the child folders which in turn contain the actual files

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code to share?  If you are trying to reference files for the current day you could always use `DateTime` and `parse` what you want.

Comment: `Day(Date)` resulted in illegal file path characters?

Comment: I am using a check for filedate and taking a a specific filepath through a textbox.  I want particular files, mostly either ones with today's date or yesterday's date, but some have no date in the filename or directory at all.  Since there isn't a lot of consistency, I would love to enter code "+ DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") +" in the textbox per individual filepath as I load them via the form and have the program execute like it does in VBA, but I get Illegal characters with the double quotes in the method File.GetLastWriteTime() and my Emailer when the filepath is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `System.IO.Path.Combine(...)` to handle chaining directories together (it takes care of extra slashes for you). In your combine, use `String.Format(SomeFormatString, token1value, toke2value, etc.)` to give you the name you were wanting.

C# uses `+` to append strings instead of `&` in older VB.

```
"My Date: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

An example of this with the `String.Format` I showed above would be

```
string.Format("My Date: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
```

Comment: This and I'd say it would be wise to take in a root folder path in your `TextBox` instead. Then you can use `Regex` to make patterns to match like `(Dec-[\d]+|December)` for December after the root.

Comment: Hmmm, that is helpful.  I suppose I could enter any old date in the textbox with my filepath that is the same as the filepath and then use regex to find and replace certain patterns with the most current date.

Answer (score 0):

The [ToString overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) of the DateTime structure will allow you to format a date as the Month name, etc.

```
var x = DateTime.Today.ToString("MMMM"); // December
```

You can include other characters in the format string as well, for example to get `Dec-19` you can use:

```
var x = DateTime.Today.ToString("MMM-dd"); // Dec-19
```

[TyCobb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692352/varying-filepaths-in-c-sharp/20692482#20692482) covers combining the formatted date into a path using [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine) (which I generally recommend).

You can also use [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be) to insert a [formatted value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format) into a string, which is often easier to read and leads to fewer mistakes. For example, to generate your first example, you could use the following:

```
var path =
    String.Format("V:....\{0:MMM-dd}\filename{0:M-d-yyyy}.xml", DateTime.Today);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm following what you're saying about Day(Date), you might try some thing like this in C#:

```
MyObject.SomeMethod("some string " + dateValue.ToString("ddd") + " more string data");
```

Where dateValue is a DateTime object and the "ddd" parameter tells the ToString method to return a three character abbreviation of the day of the week (e.g. 'Wed').

For more information on using ToString with DateTime objects to extract various parts of the date, see
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762911(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2